# Angular: How to handle WebSocket error: ErrorEvent?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, runtime-error, mqtt

I have created an angular application which uses more or less the ngx-mqtt protocoll. But upon running the application I get the following error in the NodeJS console (as seen in the screenshot).

```
WebSocket error: ErrorEvent {
  [Symbol(kTarget)]: _WebSocket {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      open: [Function (anonymous)],
      error: [Function (anonymous)],
      close: [Function (anonymous)],
      message: [Function (anonymous)]
    },
    _eventsCount: 4,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _binaryType: 'nodebuffer',
    _closeCode: 1006,
    _closeFrameReceived: false,
    _closeFrameSent: false,
    _closeMessage: <Buffer >,
    _closeTimer: null,
    _extensions: {},
    _paused: false,
    _protocol: '',
    _readyState: 2,
    _receiver: null,
    _sender: null,
    _socket: null,
    _bufferedAmount: 0,
    _isServer: false,
    _redirects: 0,
    _autoPong: true,
    _url: 'ws://localhost:1884/',
    _req: null,
    __zone_symbol__openfalse: [ [ZoneTask] ],
    __zone_symbol__errorfalse: [ [ZoneTask] ],
    __zone_symbol__closefalse: [ [ZoneTask] ],
    __zone_symbol__messagefalse: [ [ZoneTask] ],
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  [Symbol(kType)]: 'error',
  [Symbol(kError)]: AggregateError
      at __node_internal_ (node:internal/errors:174:15)
      at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1114:18)
      at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1667:5) {
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    [errors]: [ [Error], [Error] ]
  },
  [Symbol(kMessage)]: ''
}
```

I get this error when I use `(global as any).WebSocket = require('ws');`.If I dont use it I get the error **WebSocket is not defined**.

`(global as any).WebSocket = require('ws');` ==> ws.polly-fill.ts (TS File) which is imported in main.ts.

You can find the whole project under the following link: [[https://github.com/sohaib-96/angular-mqtt]](https://github.com/sohaib-96/angular-mqtt)